# Issues with using AJAX and JQuery to multiselect and capture information from JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, multi-select

I have a live search function that parses information from a JSON file using AJAX and jQuery, and then is clickable. What I'm struggling to figure out is how to have the value (in this case, "happy" or "fat") populate a multiselect, and then once that's accomplished, capture the rest of the data in that JSON array to be utilized later.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 $('#search').keyup(function(){
  $('#result').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
  var searchField = $('#search').val();
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  $.getJSON('coretype.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    if (value.identifier.search(expression) != -1)
    {
     $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"> '+value.identifier+'</li>');
    }
   });   
  });
 });

$('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
  $('#search').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
  $("#result").html('');
 });
});
```

I have gotten all the way to having the value be clickable, and have been unsuccessful figuring out the rest from there.

Here's the JSON file:

```
 [
      {
        "identifier":"Happy",
        "progressbar1": 3,
        "progressbar2": 2,
        "progressbar3": -2
      },
        {
        "identifier":"Fat",
        "progressbar1": -3,
        "progressbar2": -2,
        "progressbar3": 2
      }
    ]
```

Ideally I'd like javascript to be able to capture the "progressbarX" values when someone types in the identifier, although I figure there's a much easier way to accomplish this...

```
<!-- Search -->
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   <h2 align="center">EnneaTest</h2>
   <br /><br />
   <div align="center">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="trait type" class="form-control" />
   </div>
   <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
   <br />
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the [Plunker file](https://plnkr.co/edit/94lGwhF3WzndbJKN7Kc4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a kind of autocomplete drop down for search from json. And once one of the options from that dropdown is selected, I add that to the result list. At that time the whole object is pushed into searchObjects object. When the item from the list is clicked, that text is used to search the object associated with it.  Hope this helps..

```
           <!-- Search -->
    <br /><br />
    <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
     <h2 align="center">EnneaTest</h2>
     <br /><br />
     <div align="center">
      <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="trait type" class="form-control" />
     </div>
     <div id="searchResult"></div>
     <div>
         <ul class="list" id="result" style="color: red;"></ul>
     </div>

     <br />
    </div>



       <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });


        $('#search').keyup(function(){
                    var searchField = $('#search').val();
                    var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
                    var output = '<div class="row">';

                    $.getJSON('coretype.json', function(data) {
                      $.each(data, function(key, val){
                        if (val.identifier.search(regex) !== -1)  {
                            console.log(val);
                            var thisVal = JSON.stringify(val);
                          output += "<h5 onclick='addToList("+thisVal+")'>" + val.identifier + "</h5>";
                        }
                      });
                      output += '</div>';
                      $('#searchResult').html(output);
                    }); 
        });





        $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
          var click_text = $(this).text();
          console.log(click_text);
          var thisObj = [];
          thisObj = findObject(click_text);
          console.log(thisObj);
         });
       });

       var searchObjs = [];


        function addToList(obj) {
            //console.log(obj);
            $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class">'+obj.identifier+'</li>');
            $('#searchResult').html('');


            var item = {};
            item ["identifier"] = obj.identifier;
            item ["progressbar1"] = obj.progressbar1;
            item ["progressbar2"] = obj.progressbar2;
            item ["progressbar3"] = obj.progressbar3;

            searchObjs.push(item);

            console.log(searchObjs);

        }  

        function findObject(identifier) {
            var found = 0;
            for (var i = 0, len = searchObjs.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (searchObjs[i].identifier === identifier) {
                    return searchObjs[i]; // Return as soon as the object is found
                    found = 1;
                }
            }
            if(found === 0) {
                return null; // The object was not found    
            }

        } ;           

        </script>
```